# Convert to uppercase the keys that are being pressed from any input

Tags: angular

I have a query, I want that as I press a key it becomes uppercase, I need it for an input that will accept strings of type: P79COL01 (combination of letter and numbers), but as the filter in the backend is In capital letters, I need that if I enter p it converts to P, and I can search the backend for everything that contains P, that this is already done.

The code of my input:

```
     <ng-container *ngIf="filterValue==='Equipo Origen'">
              <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput (keyup)="loadpaginator()" placeholder="Equipo Origen"  type="text" [(ngModel)]="EquipoOrigenValue" uppercase>
              </mat-form-field> 
          </ng-container>
```

As you can see there is a keyup that is activated just press a key to search for the backend (carried out with Django Rest Framework)

Comment: or just make the back end uppercase it before it is used.

Comment: How so? I put it like this: <input matInput (keyup) = "loadpaginator ()" placeholder = "Locality Origin" type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "LocalityOrigenValue" uppercase> and nothing happens

Comment: He said, on your server side convert it to UPPERCASE before you perform search, not on client side.

Comment: have you tried `[ngModel]="EquipoOrigenValue.toUpperCase()" (ngModelChange)="EquipoOrigenValue = $event.toUpperCase()"`? I'm not sure if that will work, but seems like the least amount of effort.

Comment: Adding the line  (ngModelChange) = "EquipoOrigenValue = $ event.toUpperCase ()" worked. Thanks @Reactgular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ngModelChange` event to assign change and add angular `uppercase` pipe to `ngModel`

```
<input [ngModel]="EquipoOrigenValue | uppercase" (ngModelChange)="EquipoOrigenValue = $event">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use CSS style?

```
<ng-container *ngIf="filterValue==='Equipo Origen'">
<mat-form-field>
   <input
      style="text-transform:uppercase"
      matInput
      (keyup)="loadpaginator()"
      placeholder="Equipo Origen"
      type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="EquipoOrigenValue"
      uppercase>
</mat-form-field> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: it does not work, because it sends it in lowercase to the backend, although on the screen it is shown in uppercase

Comment: He wants the data itself to be uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your function loadpaginator() and add below code inside it

```
loadpaginator() {
  this.EquipoOrigenValue = this.EquipoOrigenValue.toUpperCase();
}
```

Since EquipoOrigenValue is a dualbind modal it will automatically change the value also.